# How to use just the eyedropper with HTML input type="color"

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I need an eyedropper tool for a project I'm working on and the one that is included with `<input type="color">` is perfect. Is there a way to use just the eyedropper without displaying the entire color picker interface?

Ideally, I would like to use [React Color](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/) for the color picker, but with the eyedropper from `<input type="color">`. I know `<input type="color">` is dependent on the OS and doesn't work on every browser, but is what I'm asking possible?

Comment: Did you find an answer? Thanks!